# Concurrent race condition?

Tags: java, concurrency

This class extends `Thread` and once it is created, the thread is started. This is the code:

```
class Controller extends Thread implements ConfigurationObserver{

    private int refreshMS;

    //...

    @Override
    public void notifyConfiguration(ConfigurationModel config) {
        refreshMS = config.getRefreshMs();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //...
        while (true) {

            try {
                Thread.sleep(refreshMS);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                //...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It follows the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). This class will subscribe itself to the `ConfigurationController` which will notify him every time there is a change in any of the configuration parameters, through `notifyConfiguration(...)`method.

What makes me a little insecure about this, is the attribute `refresMS`. Configuration is changed through the GUI (Thread #1) and affects the attribute of `Controller` class (Thread #2) which is read from the running thread of that class (Thread #3).

**Q1:** Could this become a race condition?
**Q2:** If so, what is it the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I did is the one pingw33n suggested. Using the keyword `volatile`.

```
class Controller extends Thread implements ConfigurationObserver{

    private volatile int refreshMS;
    //...
 }
```

Quote from [Brian Goetz's Managing Volatility](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp06197/index.html)

> Volatile variables share the visibility features of synchronized, but
>   none of the atomicity features. This means that threads will
>   automatically see the most up-to-date value for volatile variables.

Which means that `volatile` could be used instead of `synchronized` in very few cases. But luckly this is one of them, since `int` is writed atomicly (no thread can read its value while other one is modifying it).

Therefore, as Stephen C said, this does not eliminates the race condition, it only makes it really rare to happen. In my case, if the `refresMS` is readed with an old value by the running thread is not a big deal (if it is something that barely happens).

Answer (score 3):

> Q1: Could this become a race condition?

Yes.  Sort of.  The `run()` method could end up using a value of `refreshMS` that is stale.

> Q2: If so, what is it the best way to solve this problem?

This minimizes the race condition:

```
class Controller extends Thread implements ConfigurationObserver{
    private int refreshMS;
    public synchronized void notifyConfiguration(ConfigurationModel config) {
        refreshMS = config.getRefreshMs();
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            ...
            synchronized (this) {
                rms = refreshMS;
            }
            Thread.sleep(rms);
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

You cannot entirely eliminate the race condition without making the `sleep` call *inside* the synchronized block.  (That would cause a thread that calls `notifyConfiguration` to block for a potentially unbounded length of time.  Bad idea.)

---

Now, this is all well and good, but you should also ask yourself whether the race condition is likely to have harmful effect on the application's execution.

Comment: Or make `refreshMS` `volatile`.

Comment: @pingw33n - there is also a minimal race condition if you use `volatile`.

Comment: In OP's question there's no other code inside `while` loop except `try...catch`. Otherwise you're right.

Comment: Well, a stale value is not that bad, the problem comes when is not even a value, is just rubish. I think writing on an int in Java is atomic, but imagine it is not. You could end up reading a value that has half of its bits representing the new value and the other half the old value! that`s scary...

Comment: @pingw33n as I said to Stephen C, I think volatile can not prevent from reading rubish.

Comment: @eversor - a partial read of a `volatile int` won't happen.  The JLS guarantees this.  (A `volatile long` is a different matter though ...)

Comment: @pingw33n - I know that.  Despite that, there is *still* a minimal race condition between exiting the `synchronized` block and calling `Thread.sleep(...)`.  (Or between fetching the value of the `volatile` variable and calling `Thread.sleep(...)`.)  There are very small time-windows for these race conditions to occur in, but the time-windows are not zero width.

Comment: So both methods, synchronize and volatile work exactly the same to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes ... and both fail for the same reason.  The problem is you can't stop `refreshMS` changing in that small time-window without some majorly harmful side-effects.

Comment: I see, ok I think I will use volatile, the consequences of unlucky timing in this case are not harmful, having that is impossible to have an int with an inconsistent value. But I think that if the consequences where harmful indeed, you should implement some kind of mutual exclusion with semaphores or blocking queues...